# even single line htaccess gives 500 internal error

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

My code is working fine on another server. I'm just moving host. Code is exactly the same. I just copied and pasted to new location.

with a blank htaccess file I do not give any errors. But if I type even a single line for example

```
RewriteEngine on
```

I get 500 error.

Here is whole htaccess file to be mentioned

```
RewriteEngine on


# Forcing HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$

# hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?id=$1&amount=$2 [L]

Options -Indexes

<FilesMatch "\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png|ico|css|js|swf)$">

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1728000, public, must-revalidate"
  </IfModule>

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: If you get a 500 response then you need to check your server's error log for details of the error. But if `RewriteEngine on` alone is triggering a 500 error then it would seem to suggest that mod_rewrite is not enabled?

Comment: you might want to add some basic logs, loke the apache server logs, which modules your apache is build with and started with, your OS version.

Comment: DocRoot then how can I enable it?

Comment: @roberthofer: Are you the admin on that machine?

Comment: Apache mode rewrite was not enabled. Problem solved when I enabled it. Thanks guys.